# Parsing complex string data

Tags: java, regex

I have a complex strings like the following:

```
$company=>Company(code->MyCompany)
$brand=>Brand(code->Brand_1, company->$company)
```

and then I prepare objects out of them as follows:

```
Macro [key=$company, type=Company, map={code=MyCompany}]
Macro [key=$brand, type=Brand, map={ company=$company, code=Brand_1}]
```

using the following code for parsing. Is there a better way?

```
public class Macro {

    private String key;

    private String type;

    private Map<String, String> map;
}

public static Macro getMacro(String str) {
    final Macro macro = new Macro();
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1).split(",")).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.stream().forEach(a ->
        {
            final String[] ar = a.split("->");
            map.put(ar[0], ar[1]);
        });
    }
    str = str.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
    final String[] s = str.split("=>");
    macro.setMap(map);
    macro.setKey(s[0]);
    macro.setType(s[1]);
    return macro;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)");
```

The Pattern is always the same so you may just as well make it a `private static final` constant. This will avoid having to recompile the pattern each time.

---

```
Arrays.asList(/*..*/).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why this dance? Arrays.asList returns a List. You only do a stream on the return result.

```
    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1).split(","));
    list.stream().forEach(a ->
    {
        final String[] ar = a.split("->");
        map.put(ar[0], ar[1]);
    });
```

However a Pattern an return a Stream split according to the pattern directly:

```
Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");


COMMA_PATTERN.splitAsStream(matcher.group(3)).forEach(a ->
{
    //...
}
```

---

You can use a single match of a Pattern to find both the leading values and the string inside the parenthesis:

```
private static final Pattern FULL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\$\\w+)\\s*=>\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\(([^)]+)\\)$");
private static final Pattern KEY_VALUE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*->\\s*([\\$\\w]+)");
private static final Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");

public static Macro getMacro(String str) {
    final Macro macro = new Macro();
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    final Matcher matcher = FULL_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    if(!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }

    COMMA_PATTERN.splitAsStream(matcher.group(3)).forEach(a ->
    {
        final Matcher kvMatcher = KEY_VALUE_PATTERN.matcher(a);
        if(!kvMatcher.matches()){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }

        map.put(kvMatcher.group(1), kvMatcher.group(2));
    });
    macro.setMap(map);
    macro.setKey(matcher.group(1));
    macro.setType(matcher.group(2));
    return macro;

}
```

You'll note I added `\\s*` to various points in each pattern, This lets you ignore the whitespace that may surround the operators.

The `\\w` in a Pattern means a word character. If you only want alphanumeric +undescore then you'llneed to replace each instance of it with `[\\p{Alnum}_]`

Comment: Thank you sir. When i check your Full pattern ^(\\$\\w+)\\s*=>\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\(([^)]+)\\)$ to the following regex tool https://regex101.com/, it is not matching anything. Will it be possible for you to have a look

Comment: @SaurabhKumar if I insert `^(\$\w+)\s*=>\s*(\w+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)$` into regex101 it properly matches your test strings: https://regex101.com/r/E7uvML/1

Comment: Correct but for (\w+)\s*->\s*(\w+) regex sir it's not matching the following str for example company->$company. Its goes into IllegalArgument.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Ah I see it was missing the `$`, should have been `(\w+)\s*->\s*([\$\w]+)` fixed in the answer

Comment: Yup. Thank you very much for helping me out. I learnt new things about regex from you :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplifications:

- `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` can be shorter (and faster) as `Arrays.stream(...)`
- In the same vein, the code collects the stream into a list, just to restream the list. Additionally using an `Action` (as in `forEach`) to **collect** results is semantically questionable. The whole while-loop should be written like this:

  ```
  while (matcher.find()) {
      map = Arrays.stream(matcher.group(1).split(","))
          .map(content -> content.split("->")
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
  }
  ```
- Since the `Pattern` instance you have does not change, I'd extract it into a static variable
- Instead of making this an external static method, I'd put it into the `Macro` class. This enables calling it as follows: `Macro.fromString(...)`.

Last but not least this is a pretty nicely usable place for regex as follows:

```
static final Pattern macroPattern = 
    Pattern.compile("(\\$[^=]+)=>([A-Z][^\\(]+)\\((([^-]+)->([^\\)]+)(?:\\s*,\\s*)?\\)");
```

Now if java had named capture groups this would suddenly become much easier (*~hint, hint, nudge nudge*). How to use this pattern is something left as exercise to the reader

Comment: But Java does have [named-capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname)! `(?<key>\$.+?)=>` etc. Also, your regex does not compile. You have to use double backslashes in string literals to represent a single backslash in the regular expression.

Comment: thanks for catching the backslashes and the apparently needed refresher on named capture groups...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Stream.forEach(Consumer)` with a `Consumer` whose action accesses shared state (namely the local and `final` variable `map`) without taking care of synchronization (a `HashMap` is not thread-safe). [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is [bad](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). `Stream.forEach(Consumer)` might look like a simple for-each loop, but it is more than that, because unlike the latter, it might process multiple stream elements simultaneously in multiple threads, so accessing shared state without synchronization is dangerous. A safer approach would have been to use [`forEachOrdered(Consumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead of `forEach(Consumer)`.

The solution proposed by Vogel612 for this problem is even more elegant, but, technically, it is not equivalent to your procedure, because your procedure doesn't create a new `Map` for every iteration of `while (matcher.find())`, as opposed to Vogel612's code, which assigns a new `Map` to `map` for every loop iteration. However, the `while (matcher.find())` loop is probably a design flaw anyway, because as far as I understand your question, the input string is not supposed to contain multiple parentheses-enclosed "maps" (not to be confused with key-value-"mappings"). This can be rectified by using a single regular expression for the whole input string, as the other answers have already suggested.

Comment: FWIW making "synchronization" an issue when referring to a local variable is a separate level of overkill. You're of course correct in principle, but it doesn't matter that much, given that the stream isn't a `parallelStream` in the first place. Unless there is a `parallel` in the pipeline, Java / JIT is **highly unlikely** if not disallowed from making the Stream parallel

Comment: @Vogel612 It is irrelevant whether the variable is local or a field. The point is that it can be accessed concurrently and therefore behave in an unexpected manner. However, you're right, the documentation of `Collection.stream()` says explicitly that it returns a sequential stream. Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of that. Still, I think it is better to point out a practice that has the potential of causing trouble, even if, in this particular case, it is unproblematic.